# pyspark: get unique items in each column of a dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe containing 1 million rows and 560 columns. I need to find the count of unique items in each column of the dataframe.
I have written the following code to achieve this but it is getting stuck and taking too much time to execute:

```
count_unique_items=[]

for j in range(len(cat_col)):
    var=cat_col[j]
    count_unique_items.append(data.select(var).distinct().rdd.map(lambda r:r[0]).count())
```

### cat_col contains the column names of all the categorical variables

Is there any way to optimize this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check number of unique values in each column of a matrix in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707361/check-number-of-unique-values-in-each-column-of-a-matrix-in-spark)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `approxCountDistinct` or `countDistinct`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import approxCountDistinct, countDistinct

counts = df.agg(approxCountDistinct("col1"), approxCountDistinct("col2")).first()
```

but counting distinct elements is expensive.

Comment: I have many attributes in my data, most of them are redundant as they just have one distinct value in the whole data. So, I would need to remove this columns for my analysis. Which is why, I need to count the distinct elements in each column. Is there any other effective way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, but as stated above, distinct element counting is expensive. The single * passes in each value as an argument, so the return value will be 1 row X N columns. I frequently do a `.toPandas()` call to make it easier to manipulate later down the road.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, approxCountDistinct
distvals = df.agg(*(approxCountDistinct(col(c), rsd = 0.01).alias(c) for c in 
df.columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get every different element of each column with

```
df.stats.freqItems([list with column names], [percentage of frequency (default = 1%)])
```

This returns you a dataframe with the different values, but if you want a dataframe with just the count distinct of each column, use this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct

df.select( [ countDistinct(cn).alias("c_{0}".format(cn)) for cn in df.columns ] ).show()
```

The part of the count, taken from here: [check number of unique values in each column of a matrix in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707361/check-number-of-unique-values-in-each-column-of-a-matrix-in-spark)